# What should I use to seal between granite countertops?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, sealant

My kitchen has granite countertops and upstands. The sealant between the individual countertop pieces and between the countertops and upstands requires renewing.

What kind of sealant should I use ?

---

Edit: Added picture
[image]

Comment: What is an "upstand"? Not a term I'm familiar with. Including a picture may help. What is there currently? I'd imagine that it's some sort of color match grout or caulk...

Comment: @FreeMan   Think we know them as backsplashes.

Comment: @crip659 thanks for clarifying but then what is a worktop, op used three terms countertop, worktop and upstands.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose Sorry, my mistake, worktop = countertop. The upstands are the vertical pieces attached to the walls.

Comment: @FreeMan Upstands are grey. Backsplashes are gray.

Comment: @FreeMan I have added a photo, hopefully it is clear now. Sorry about that !

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. "Upstand" is British for the American "backsplash". Truck/lorry, elevator/lift, it's all so confusing. :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Scrape the grout line in the counter top to remove dirt and achieve a depth of perhaps 8mm (just over 1/4in).
2. Select a grout and colour matched caulking.

They can be of different brands, but some brands offer specifically coded colour matching. For instance Mapei has colour coded grout and colour coded caulking to match.

3. Apply grout and seal with grout sealant.

There are different grades of sealant available. Some are a penetrating liquid for a reasonable good protection, typically used on shower and bathroom floors in homes. Other are a glaze or epoxy based, which are more durable and more water tight, usually used in commercial showers (e.g. gym, pools).

Should there be potential movement between the two slabs of the counter top, you should upgrade the grout to an epoxy grout and deepen the grove further, perhaps to 1/2in. Epoxy grout looks like grout but will form a much stronger and supporting bond to the granite than regular grout.

If you cannot find the desired colour for the epoxy grout, apply epoxy grout to a depth of about 1/4in. Then apply the coloured regular grout overtop.

4. Apply caulk of matching colour to the backsplash.

Although this seam could be grouted and sealed like the granite joint, this is not recommended due to potential movement between the two: the counter top rests on the cabinet bases, the backsplash is fastened to the wall.

Answer (score 2):

Given that your countertop joint looks pretty wide, I'd try to scrape out what you can, then re-epoxy, with a black resin, e.g.: [https://www.amazon.com/Granite-Repair-Quartz-Countertop-Porcelain/dp/B0BF16W6SQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BF16W6SQ)

You may need to do some wetsanding and/or polishing of the epoxy when done.

For the backsplash (upstand?) you can just scrape out what's there and use a clear (or black) caulk.